# Как в jquery подключить класс из таблицы стилей?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Есть скрипт с кодом `jquery`, который добавляет свойство `.activEv` (подчеркивание синей линией), выбранной странице (ajax-контент). Строкой `loadContent(0);` подключается контент по-умолчанию. Как подключить свойство из таблицы стилей к контенту по умолчанию? Пробовал не получилось...

```
loadContent(0).addClass('activeEv');
loadContent(0).loadClass('activEv');
```

Файл CSS:

```
.activeEv{
border-bottom: 2px solid #0a88d3;
color: #0a88d3;
}
```

Скрипт в коде:

```
       <div class="container ">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav centermenu">
             <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page1"><a name="top">page1 </a></li>
             <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page2"><a>page2 </a></li>
             <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page3"><a>page3 </a></li>
             <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page4"><a>page4 </a></li>
             <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page5"><a>page5 </a></li>
           </ul>              
        </div>

     <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var tpls = ['page1.blade.php', 'page2.blade.php', 'page3.blade.php', 'page4.blade.php', 'page5.blade.php'];

                $('.loadBtn').click(function(){

                    $('.loadBtn').removeClass('activeEv');
                    $(this).addClass('activeEv');

                    loadContent($(this).index());
                });
                loadContent(0).addClass('activeEv');   //loadClass('activEv');

                function loadContent(index) {
                    if (!tpls[index]) return;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: tpls[index],
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("#content").html(html);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: К сведению: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/178779

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы вызываете `.addClass()` на результат `loadContent()` который `undefined`, потому что функция ничего не возвращает. Вам нужно вызывать `.addClass()` в AJAX колбеке. Для этого можно сам колбек передавать в `loadContent()`:

```
loadContent(0, function(html) {
  $('#content').html(html);
  $('.loadBtn').eq(0).addClass('activeEv');
});

function loadContent(index, callback) {
  if (!tpls[index]) return;
  $.ajax({
    url: tpls[index],
    cache: false,
    success: callback || null
  });
}
```

Comment: код подчеркивает ВЕСЬ контент, а как сделать чтоб tpls только подчеркивало?

Comment: @Александр, обновил ответ.

Comment: Alex Zhulin, спасибо, но результата никакого....теперь и контент НЕ подчеркивает...

Comment: @Александр, вам нужно добавить класс `activeEv` первому `<li  class="loadBtn"  value="page1"></li>` элементу?

Comment: Alex Zhulin да, именно так

Comment: Alex, я добавил вторым классом, все отлично, спасибо Вам огромное